# Set different css classes for the different select elements of date input with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

How do I set different css classes for the different selects(day, month) generate by:

```
 <%= f.input :birthday, :as => :date, :discard_year => true,
                          :order => [:day, :month] %>
```

I just found a way to set the css class for the overall input.

It doesn't have to be simple_form. It can be regular rails code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to solve it with `select_date`, even with `simple-form`. *`simple-form` maps `:as => 'date'` to `date_select`.*

Although you can split `date_select` into a [`select_day`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_day) and [`select_month`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-select_month) inputs and pass the respective css class at `html_options` for each input.